# Eclipse performance on my G4 is horrific - any thoughts on a replacement?

Tags: java, performance, eclipse

I have a 5yr old G4 PowerBook that I use while travelling, and I had intended to get some work done whilst I am away for the next few weeks.

Eclipse just seems to be horrendously slow on it. I've tried tweaking the memory allocated to the VM, but it doesn't seem to do very much :)

Any thoughts as to why it's so slow? I don't get this problem on my desktop - and that has less RAM, although it's running Linux.

If I'm flogging a dead horse, what would you recommend as a Java development environment?

Ideally, I would want good code completion, as my mental capacity is somewhat limited :)

---

*Thank you all kindly for your responses. I've just set-up netbeans on the laptop, removed some of the cruft, and imported my project. After taking about half an hour scanning the project (there are a ton of external libraries) I am pleased to say that it is very responsive. Code completion is working nicely (although not quite as intuitive as eclipse). Unfortunately, I seem to be able to only select one of your answers - although i'll be using  many of them. A new laptop is on the cards for when I get back from my trip.*

Comment: Sounds to me like your IDE has become a bit of a crutch.

Comment: i don't know the details, but there was some rumors about sun's JVM never got as optimised for PPC as for Intel.  maybe it's possible to use an IBM JVM?

Comment: Well, given the choice, I would like a nice IDE as well.  Who wouldn't?  Have fun developing C# in Notepad++ (I don't use Java).

Comment: +1: I have done a TON of development in notepad (php, html, c#, and java) and I actually prefer it over the horrendous beast that is Eclipse.

Comment: Please edit this question such that it isn't argumentative and abrasive. (referring to someone else's work - which you didn't have to pay for - as "Horrific" isn't conducive to a good discussion.)  Perhaps say something like, "Horrific Eclipse performance - any thoughts on how to improve my Java development environment?"

Comment: If a crutch saves me hours a day looking up class members in javadocs, then I'm quite happy to have that crutch :) Obviously, in this particular case its wasting me hours, which is why i'm looking for an alternative.

Comment: Eclipse wants lots and lots of RAM.  If you swap, you have too little.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I've been using Eclipse for years, and I found that it never ran acceptably fast on my Mac until I got Ganymede (Eclipse 3.4) and ran it on my Core 2 Duo Macbook w/ 2GB of RAM. Before I had both of those things, it was only ever bearable on Linux or Windows. I'd recommend upgrading your computer. :-)  Eclipse is, after all, a beast of a program no matter how you spin it.

Comment: I think I'll do just that - the way its running at the moment it will have paid for itself within a week. How responsive is it on your macbook? It runs like a dream on my linux desktop with 1GB RAM (even with firefox and evolution).

Comment: It runs very acceptably on my Dell E1505, 2GB RAM, Windows XP (I can even run a VMWare image at the same time.)

Comment: It's really snappy. We're talking almost no lag, ever, including when Firefox and Terminal are running. Even when accessing files on my network drive over a G network it's pretty fast. I'd say its surpassed the speed I've experienced for years with the Windows version, which is very surprising.

Comment: Oh my! - Ive just had a look through the apple store and now I'm salivating and staring at my wallet, wondering if I should either be going on this holiday or buying a macbook...

Comment: The obvious answer to this problem is to do BOTH and go into debt at the same time. =D

Answer (score 3):

I've found two primary limiters to Eclipse performance:

1. Available RAM (2GB is a minimum on a Windows PC)
2. Hard drive speed (I've had lots of issues with slow and/or highly fragmented drives.)

Laptops have notoriously slow drives - and it's often compounded by the drive going into "power save" mode (thus spinning more slowly.)

We also used to run Eclipse on top of ClearCase dynamic views....talk about a performance beast....

It may also be worth your time to trim down Eclipse (disabling unneeded plugins and the like.)  Click "Help"->"Manage Configuration" to get to the interface where you can do this.  The Eclipse distributions come with lots and lots of powerful tools - many of which most of us never use.

Comment: You bring back horrible memories of trying to get Eclipse to respond when working with CC. Terrifyingly slow, but always a good excuse for a 20 minute coffee break. :-)

Comment: Works great with CC snapshot views.  But dynamic views are essentially the plague.

Comment: what are you setting -Xmx to with 2G of ram?

Comment: -Xmx setting depends on the size of the project I'm working on.  1024m is not uncommon.

Answer (score 2):

If you are worried about speed  use something like vim or textmate.

Otherwise you have to realize, Eclipse comes with a LOT built in with it, hence the long loading time. If you find yourself not using most of its features then just use a text editor.

Neatbeans is supposedly more light weight.

Answer (score 2):

I love IntelliJ from JetBrains.

I used Eclipse for four years and loved it.  But since I was shown IntelliJ I've never gone back.  I feel strongly enough where I pony up the cash to buy a personal license.  Worth every cent.

Comment: I agree, IntelliJ is awesome.  I hated eclipse's performance and random crashing...  like any IDE, you kinda have to wrestle intellij a bit, but it's worth it.   i've used it on mac and pc.

Answer (score 2):

In my experience Java is just not that responsive on the Mac. A fairly fresh Eclipse on my 3 GB MBP feels slower than my work machine, which is 2 GB Dell D620 with lots of projects.

Want to try a crazy idea? Install linux on your PB G4 and try running Eclipse in that. Worth a shot.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend giving IntelliJ a try.  It might run a bit faster for you, so it's worth a try.  It's made by JetBrains, the same company that makes ReSharper and TeamCity.  (If you like it you can buy it... it's free to try).

http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/

Good luck with your quest!

Answer (score 0):

Eclipse is a one of the best IDEs for Java. What is the configuration of your G4? One thing you can do to make things snappier is disable automatic building in the background. You can do this by unchecking Project->Build Automatically. Doing so will prevent eclipse from continuously building in the background and it will be more responsive to your editing needs. Also if you are using the web development plugin you can disable jsp and xml validation.

Answer (score 0):

I like Netbeans, it is relatively small and fast but since Oracle is now the owner of Sun I don´t know about the future of it.

Comment: Thanks for the info about Oracle and Sun, I wasn't aware of that yet... it looks as if Oracle is shopping big in the Java-world (BEA and now Sun).

Answer (score 0):

I've had that problem a few times. I've found that some systems that run Eclipse like a pig do well with Aptana or NetBeans. I'd try those first, as they are both pretty powerful.

Comment: Aptana is just a web-centric, eye-candy-heavy IDE built on top of Eclipse.

Comment: Aptana is running a stripped down version of Eclipse 3.2 though... and I think most of the stripped out bits are the Java support so those could be the bottleneck.

Comment: Yeah, that's a good point. I did get Aptana running well on a computer that hated Eclipse, but I was just using HTML/CSS/JavaScript that time. So forget Aptana for doing Java work.

Comment: And I seem to recall that Aptana completely mangled my installation of Eclipse, and of course refused to uninstall...

Comment: @Nikhil, are you talking about the Aptana plugin for Eclipse, or the Aptana standalone?

Answer (score 0):

I would definitely ***not*** recommend IntelliJ Idea if speed is your overriding concern. I personally find it just as slow, if not slower than eclipse... It too is a dog.

By way of example - If idea crashes, which it generally does on a daily basis, then **all** projects must be re-indexed (a lengthy process) **whether open at the time or not**; an excruciating process, especially on sub-optimal boxes. The kicker is that it also re-indexes the entire JDK at the same time.

I think it sad indictment of desktop java on the whole that a decent, powerful IDE cannot, it seems, be implemented on top of it offering anywhere near acceptable performance.

I've worked with netbeans, eclipse, idea and also with visual studio. The performance comparison between the former 3 and the latter is striking!

Comment: Try the current version 8.1.2. Very fast and stable.

Comment: That's not what I'm seeing TBH. We upped to 8.1.2 a week or so back and it seemed to follow the exact same pattern - every time they upgrade, it gets slower. 5 was a hell of a lot faster (but still slow).